# How to rename a node right after creation with jsTree jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I use the jsTree plugin to create a directory tree.

Right click a node, should open a `contextmenu` where the user can create a new child node and assign a custom name to it.

So everything works fine except renaming the node.

I did following:

```
//create node (inside handler of contextmenu) 
self.dirtree.jstree(true).create_node('#' + $(this).attr('id'));

//open node and edit it (inside event handler)
if (event.type == 'create_node') {
    self.dirtree.jstree(true).open_node('#' + data.node.parent);
    self.dirtree.jstree(true).edit($('#' + data.node.parent).find('> ul').find('> li').last(), "Neuer Ordner");
}
```

The event is triggered and the parent node is also opened but the edit only removes the node name and not shows an inputfield as expected.
if I only call open_node, it looks like:

[new node output without edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK6nO.png)

when I also call edit:

[new node output with edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpiyr.png)

I'm not sure what's going wrong. Since edit changes the node, the selection should be fine.

If I call edit after create_node (in the handler of the contextmenu), everything works.

```
self.dirtree.jstree(true).create_node('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
self.dirtree.jstree(true).open_node('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
self.dirtree.jstree(true).edit($('#n-' + $(this).attr('id')).find('> ul').find('> li').last(), "Neuer Ordner");
```

[call all functions in the handler of contextmenu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dok6Z.png)

Is it even posible to call edit in the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. The problem was, that open_node wasn't finished, when edit call happened. So I defined an async function instead of calling the two functions directly.

```
createAndRename: async function(parent){
    var self = this;
    await self.dirtree.jstree(true).open_node('#' + parent);
    self.dirtree.jstree(true).edit($('#' + parent).find('> ul').find('> li').last(), "Neuer Ordner");
},
```

Comment: can you please provide full code, i mean how you are initiating and all :)